# Nuget manager not installing packages from internet using package manager

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have Visual Studio 2019 Commmunity edition. Whenever I download any package from Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for Solution, it throws an error

> NuGet.Protocol.Plugins.PluginException: A plugin was not found at path
> 'C:\Users \ (Current Username)\ .nuget\plugins'

I can't download any packages even when I create new empty project.

I get the same error even when I use the

```
Install-Package
```

command. Please help

Comment: Try to [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) and then restart your project to test again.

Comment: If you have caches under `C:\Users\xxx(current user name)\AppData\Local\NuGet\plugins-cache`, you can just delete them.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I tried that & I didnt work. Also I by mistakenly deleted the .nuget folder inside C:\Users\user-name\ location . Should I add it back ? 

I have no idea what kind of plugin is this nuget looking for ....I am stuck from 2 days.

Comment: Besides, which plugin did you use,[Azure Artifacts Credential Provider](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider#manual-installation-on-linux-and-mac)?

Comment: I answered my question below. 
Also no, I was downloading  Azure.Storage.Blobs -Version 12.4.4 package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answering my own question :**

I realized that there is something called

```
NUGET_PLUGIN_PATHS
```

in environment variables. It was pointing to my 'C:\Users \ (Current Username)\ .nuget\plugins' directory . I deleted that environment variable and guess what ? It started downloading packages from nuget.org using `Install-Package` command. It took me 2 days to find this solution.

Comment: removing environment variables.. and system restart worked for me... thanks